# if value in end($array) contains something to to second last

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a array with multiple elememts. I use `end($array)` to get the last element in the array. But if the last element contains a value it must take the second last element. But if the second last element also contains that value it must go to the next element. I already have written this code:

```
$g = end($array);

if($g != NULL && $g['MoreThanZero'] == true && $accountdata['bidding'] == 0) {
    $v = end(array_pop($array));
} else {
    $v = end($array);
}
```

In this code it will go till the second last element. How to make a "loop" which check last.. second last.... third last.... fourth last......

Comment: can you provide more detail about what you actually want?  `array_pop` removes the last element of the array and returns that value. `end` points to the end of the array, but `array_pop` only returns one value and actually `end` will give you a warning if the value itself isn't an array.. so what do you actually want, the value itself? Or are you looking to basically trim the array of duplicate values "padding" the end?

Comment: Give some examples,what you want to achieve and what problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a little `foreach`, mixed with `array_reverse()` to get it works :

```
$accountdata['bidding'] = 0;
$array = array(
    array('Value' => 10,   'MoreThanZero' => true),
    array('Value' => -10,  'MoreThanZero' => false),
    array('Value' => 20,   'MoreThanZero' => true),
    array('Value' => -30,  'MoreThanZero' => false),
    array('Value' => 30,   'MoreThanZero' => true),
    array('Value' => 40,   'MoreThanZero' => true),
    array('Value' => 50,   'MoreThanZero' => true)
);

$v = null;
foreach(array_reverse($array) as $g) {
    if($g != NULL && $g['MoreThanZero'] == true && $accountdata['bidding'] == 0) 
        continue;
    $v = $g;
    break;
}

var_dump($v);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_reverse() function to change order of elements and then loop through array with foreach().

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I only want the latest element or in case of array_reverse the first element. with a foreach I will have all elements?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$test = array('one','two','three','three');

function getLastElement($array = array(),$exclude=null){
    $list = array_reverse($array);
    foreach($list as $item){
        if($item!=$exclude) return $item;
    }
    return null;
}

var_dump(getLastElement($test,'three'));
```